# Modifying code to prevent SQL Injection

Tags: jdbc

Example of SQL injection

The following Java servlet code, used to perform a login function, illustrates the vulnerability by accepting user input without performing adequate input validation or escaping meta-characters:

```
String sql = "select * from user where username='" + username +"' and password='" + password + "'";
stmt = conn.createStatement();
rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
if (rs.next()) {
loggedIn = true;
    out.println("Successfully logged in");
} else {
    out.println("Username and/or password not recognized");
}
```

================

**Now please tell me how can we modify this code , so that it is free from SQL Injection**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the `PreparedStatement` class and add parameters.

See the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

You do this by cleaning up `username` and `password` so that they don't contain dangerous characters, either by escaping them or by removing them.

[This](http://xkcd.com/327/) might explain the problem better.

Answer (score 2):

Use a prepared statement instead of building your own query string : http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html

Comment: I hope you are not using Java 1.4!

Comment: Oops!  I just googled that link from my phone and posted it (didn't think to check that it was from the right version of Javadoc).  I just updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are providing the values at runtime to the particular sql query you should use preparedStatement,

along with you should better to use form tag (in the view page for eg: index.html,login.jsp etc.,) method as POST instead of GET to overcome the SQL injection